# g2 inverse in R

Tags: r, sas, matrix-inverse

While solving the normal equations in Proc mixed, SAS apparently uses something called g2 inverse (Pringle and Rayner, 1971). ginv in R gives me the moore-penrose inverse which is different. Is there any package in R that can give me the g2 inverse as SAS? It's very important for me that I get the same generalized inverse as SAS, the g2 inverse and not the moore-penrose. Basically I need to get the same fixed effect estimates in R as in SAS when (X'X) matrix is not full rank. 
Thank you.
Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about SAS and I only used the Moore-Penrose Pseudo-Inverse so far. Therefore I'm not sure if this helps, but you might want to a look at `rms::matinv()`. A similar problem has been discussed, e.g., [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-August/287058.html). The `rms` package has replaced the `Design` package mentioned in that discussion.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it. Hopefully, it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, matinv() didnt produce the same generalized inverse as  SAS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the SAS inverse easily eather with MATLAB or PROC IML, following Searle in his book Linear models: I will try to do a summary.
you can realize the columns which are linearly dependend by obtaining the rref of the coefficient matrix, then:
a) drop the rows and columns for which SAS put to zero the effect in the solution vector.
b) take the regular inverse of the matrix tha remains from a.
c) place in the original positions the inverse elements obtanined from b
d) fill in whit zeros the rows and columns that were zeroed when you did step a.

You can get more esasily the G2 inverse by using the SWEEP function of PROC IML, if you write down the aumented matrix.

I hope this can help someone else